# Ruby on Rails Tutorial, Section 10.3.3 fails on testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

Using Rails 3.1.0 and Ruby 1.9.2p290, I used listing 10.30 to test the sample_app:

```
   it "should paginate users" do
    get :index
    ...
    response.should have_selector("a", :href => "/users?page=2",
                                       :content => "2")
    ...
  end
```

The result is:

```
Failures:

  1) UsersController GET 'index' for signed-in users should paginate users
     Failure/Error: response.should have_selector("a", :href => "/users?page=2",
       expected following output to contain a <a href='/users?page=2'>2</a> tag:
```

Although the returned web page contains the following line:

```
 <a rel="next" href="/users?escape=false&amp;page=2">2</a>
```

Since I still don't understand the full usage of have_selector including its relation to regexp I changed the test as follows:

```
it "should paginate users" do
    get :index
    ...
    response.should have_selector('a', :rel => "next", 
                                       :href => "/users?escape=false&amp;page=2",
                                       :content => "2")
  end
```

And got:

```
Failures:

  1) UsersController GET 'index' for signed-in users should paginate users
     Failure/Error: response.should have_selector('a', :rel => "next",
       expected following output to contain a <a rel='next' href='/users?escape=false&amp;page=2'>2</a> tag:
       <!DOCTYPE html>
...
```

Although as I mentioned the page contains the following expression:

```
<a rel="next" href="/users?escape=false&amp;page=2">2</a>
```

So I'm guess I'm doing something wrong in trying to filter this expression.
I did some investigation on how to work with have_selector but I couldn't find anything meaningful.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please add a link to the tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following

```
  it "should paginate users" do
    get :index
    response.should have_selector("div.pagination")
    response.should have_selector("span.disabled", :content => "Previous")
    response.should have_selector("a", :href => "/users?escape=false&page=2",
                                       :content => "2")
    response.should have_selector("a", :href => "/users?escape=false&page=2",
                                       :content => "Next")
  end
```

I think the escape parameter is due to changes in will_paginate (but am not sure.)